# How can I disable gestures in the ios simulator?

Tags: ios

I am trying to test out my site using the ios simulator and I don't want the default double-tap gesture to work when the user double-clicks, since it is interfering with my site.

Is there any way to disable the double-tap gesture either in the simulator or in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to disable just the double tap gesture, and it may not be possible to disable at all.

The relavant references are the [Safari Web Content Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) and the [GestureEvent Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/GestureEventClassReference/GestureEvent/GestureEvent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009353). The first says that double tap doesn't produce a gesture event. It's possible that suppressing lower level touch events will cause the double tap not to be recognized, but that will also cause other gestures not to be recognized, which it sounds like you don't want. There are other things you can do as well such as restricting the zoom range for the site, but they all have other side effects that you may not want

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but see if you can add a doubleTap `GestureRecognizer` to your `webView` and do nothing in the `target` function.

On a side note, if your website is meant to be viewed on mobile devices, it would be advisable to leave alone the double tap gesture, as it is the standard way of zooming.